# How to override BroadleafCategoryController [Broadleaf Commerce]

Tags: spring-boot, e-commerce, broadleaf-commerce

When i try to override the `BroadleafCategoryController` `handleRequest` method everything works fine for me. But when i try to call the same method as show below with the Device parameter to identify the user device

In my Java Class CategoryController.java

```
@Controller("blCategoryController")
        public class CategoryController extends BroadleafCategoryController {

            private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CategoryController.class);

            @RequestMapping("/")
            public ModelAndView handleRequest(Device currentDevice, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        return super.handleRequest(request, response);

            }

        }
```

then when it goes inside the super method (handleRequest) i get the Category Object value as NULL.

```
Category category = (Category) request.getAttribute(CategoryHandlerMapping.CURRENT_CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
The above value should have been set through CategoryHandlerMapping

        public class CategoryHandlerMapping extends BLCAbstractHandlerMapping {
                    public static final String CURRENT_CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "category";

            protected String defaultTemplateName = "catalog/category";

            private String controllerName = "blCategoryController";


            @Override
            protected Object getHandlerInternal(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
                Category category = null;
                if (allowCategoryResolutionUsingIdParam()) {
                    category = findCategoryUsingIdParam(request);
                }

                if (category == null) {
                    category = findCategoryUsingUrl(request);
                }

                if (category != null) {
                    request.setAttribute(CURRENT_CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, category);
                    return controllerName;
                }

                return null;
            }
```

The `CategoryHandlerMapping` (provided by Broadleaf Commerce) has been configured inside a class annotated with `@Configuration` annotation and object is created inside a method annotated with `@Bean` annotation.

```
@Bean
public HandlerMapping categoryHandlerMapping() {
    CategoryHandlerMapping mapping = new CategoryHandlerMapping();
    mapping.setOrder(5);
    return mapping;
}
```

Note:- All the configuration related to Device (Spring-Mobile) is fine
Please let me know if I am missing any xml config like applicationContext.xml ?
    Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

The category controller is a little different, and is not resolved by the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` (which is what resolves your `@RequestMapping` piece). Instead, as you mentioned, the only way the `handleRequest()` method of the `CategoryController` is invoked is via the `CategoryHandlerMapping`. *That* is the piece that is handling the category URL.

It looks like you are just trying to figure out the current `Device` on the category page. Spring Mobile has a facility to do this with simply `DeviceUtils.getCurrentDevice(request)`. So:

1. Remove the `@RequestMapping` from `handleRequest()`
2. Rewrite your method like this:

   ```
   @Controller("blCategoryController")
   public class CategoryController extends BroadleafCategoryController {

       private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CategoryController.class);

       public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
           Device currentDevice = DeviceUtils.getCurrentDevice(request);
           return super.handleRequest(request, response);
       }

   }
   ```